# How to change elements selected using querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suppose I have 3 buttons:

```css
.all-buttons{
  display:flex;
  width: 100%
 }
 .bttn{
  width: 33%
  border: none;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 20px 20px;
color: white;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head><title>yes</title></head>
<body>
<div class="all-buttons">
  <button class="bttn">BUTTON1</button>
  <button class="bttn">BUTTON2</button>
  <button class="bttn">BUTTON3</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As of my understanding I can use JavaScript `const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('bttn');` which will create an array with every element with the class `'bttn'`. How do I change the style of a button? For example, say I want to change the background-color of Button2 if I click on it. How do I get Button2 using classes in javascript?
I have tried this:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('link');

Array.from(buttons).forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
               //code
    });
});
```

My end goal is to create a drop-down menu for each of the buttons but I would like to avoid adding an id for each button.
Any input is appreciated.

Comment: try below answer, hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting elements by className, you have 2 options:

1. [getElementsByClassName](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjI4ODuzsv7AhXVQkEAHfO5AtAQFnoECAkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FDocument%2FgetElementsByClassName&usg=AOvVaw1WCKsgwVn0qZ-OSv0JcJ-U) (without ".")

```js
const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('bttn');
```

2. [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) (with ".")

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.bttn');
```

And for changing the style of an element, you can use [.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property on that element:

```js
element.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
```

So this code will help you:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.bttn');

Array.from(buttons).forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    el.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  });
});
```

Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_style.asp).

Answer (score 2):

First, `document.querySelectorAll('bttn');` will not get elements with class equal to `.bttn` but it gets the elements with tag name equal to `bttn`.

You need to add the `.` like `document.querySelectorAll('.bttn');`

Then, you need to loop through with `forEach` and on each `button` add an event listener with `addEventListener` method on `click`, then you can change the color with `style` or create a class for the color and use `classList` methods.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.bttn');

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    button.classList.toggle('red');
  })
})
```

```css
.all-buttons{
  display:flex;
  width: 100%
 }
 .bttn{
  width: 33%
  border: none;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 20px 20px;
color: white;
  }

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head><title>yes</title></head>
<body>
<div class="all-buttons">
  <button class="bttn">BUTTON1</button>
  <button class="bttn">BUTTON2</button>
  <button class="bttn">BUTTON3</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps!

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.bttn'); // You must declare element's type; class (.) or id (#).

Array.from(buttons).forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
               el.style.color = "red"; // Added the line for changing the style of the button.
    });
});
```

```html
<button class="bttn">BUTTON1</button>
<button class="bttn">BUTTON2</button>
<button class="bttn">BUTTON3</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you need,

1. change element using queryseletorall
2. dropdown menu to each button
3. without using id to each button
   to achieve this try like below,

```js
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".dropbtn");
  const submenuList = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-content");

  //alert(nodeList.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
  
    nodeList[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      submenuList[i].classList.toggle("show");
      
      });
  
    
  }
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}


.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd}

.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <button  class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
   <div  class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="#">Link 1</a>
     <a href="#">Link 2</a>
     <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
 </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="#">Link- 1</a>
     <a href="#">Link- 2</a>
     <a href="#">Link- 3</a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

if any query please comment